# MySQLI Bind_param query not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to get this function I wrote to return some data from a MySQL table. Here is my function.

```
function getCompInfoIDS($id) {
    global $mysqli;
    $query = "
Select
  computers.asset,
  computers.serial,
  rooms.building_id,
  rooms.id,
  computers.assigned_person,
  computers.computer_name,
  computers.sticker,
  operating_systems.manufacturer_id,
  operating_systems.id As id1,
  computers.memory,
  computers.hard_drive,
  computers.department,
  computers.year_purchased,
  computers.po_cs_ca,
  computers.mac_address,
  computers.group_id,
  models.manufacturer_id As manufacturer_id1,
  models.id As id2,
  computers.type,
  computers.monitor_size
From
  computers Inner Join
  rooms On computers.room_id = rooms.id Inner Join
  operating_systems On computers.os_id = operating_systems.id Inner Join
  models On computers.model = models.id
 Where
  computers.id=?";
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($query);
    $stmt -> bind_param('i',$id);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($asset, $serial, $building_id, $room_id, $assigned_person, $computer_name, $sticker, $os_type_id, $os_id, $memory, $hard_drive, $department, $year_purchased, $po_cs_ca, $mac_address, $group_id, $model_type_id, $model_id, $comp_type, $monitor_size, $date_modified);
    while($stmt -> fetch()){
        $computer_info = array($asset, $serial, $building_id, $room_id, $assigned_person, $computer_name, $sticker, $os_type_id, $os_id, $memory, $hard_drive, $department, $year_purchased, $po_cs_ca, $mac_address, $group_id, $model_type_id, $model_id, $comp_type, $monitor_size, $date_modified);         
    }

    return $computer_info;
```

The query does work and I have tested it with multiple ids in phpmyadmin.

I have been following the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), and [this site](http://www.terjemar.net/php/2011/09/using-mysqli-and-parameterized-statements/) to do step by step to see what I am doing wrong. I have done `echo "test";` at various different spots in my code to see where the function is failing and I cannot find a single point of failure in the function, it's just not filling the array with results.

I tried doing `echo $asset;` right before I fill the array and nothing is shown so I don't believe that any data is actually being put into the array variables.

Answer (score 1):

You must add `$stmt->store_result();`, so your code is like this :

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($query);
$stmt -> bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($asset, $serial, $building_id, $room_id, $assigned_person, $computer_name, $sticker, $os_type_id, $os_id, $memory, $hard_drive, $department, $year_purchased, $po_cs_ca, $mac_address, $group_id, $model_type_id, $model_id, $comp_type, $monitor_size, $date_modified);
while($stmt -> fetch()){
    $computer_info = array($asset, $serial, $building_id, $room_id, $assigned_person, $computer_name, $sticker, $os_type_id, $os_id, $memory, $hard_drive, $department, $year_purchased, $po_cs_ca, $mac_address, $group_id, $model_type_id, $model_id, $comp_type, $monitor_size, $date_modified);         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should give your error like this:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line x
```

The number of selected columns from your query is not the same with the number of binded results. You only have 20 columns selected in your `SELECT` query, but your `bind_result()` has 21 variables in it.

You must be missing a column from your query. Obviously for your `$date_modified` variable. Fill up your `SELECT` query correctly for your `$date_modified` variable to bind with.